# Joining 3 Tables in One Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data set with patient information/charges (Table 1).

I am looking to achieve Table 3. Table 3 shown below has:

1. Distinct Patient Number (Patno)
2. The sum of Billed Charges for each Patno (sum billed charges then group by patno)
3. DRG Rate from Table 2. This is just matching the DRG in Table 1 to Table 2 and getting the DRG Rate Associated with it.
4. Stop loss column. If the sum of Billed Charges for a patient (found in column 2) is >275000 then (SUM of Billed Charges -275000)*.195+ DRG Rate from column 3
5. Claim total: If there is a stop loss, then the claim total is just = to the stop loss value found in column 4. ELSE, it is equal to the DRG rate.

Note, each patient has only ONE claim, but can have multiple line items as shown in table 1.

**Table 1: Raw Data**

[image: Table_1_Raw Data]

**Table 2: DRG Lookup Table**

[image: Table_2_DRG Table]

**Table 3: Result Table**

[image: Table_3_Final Claim]

Please let me know if you need any additional info. I know this is a lot to ask, honestly any tips/tricks advice will really help ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is it possible to provide insert statement to recreate the tables?

Comment: Hey, I'll email you!

Comment: Sure. kmnur@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```
SELECT PATNO, SUM([Billed Charges]) as BilledCharges,
DR.[DRG Rate], 
CASE WHEN SUM([Billed Charges]) >275000 THEN ((SUM([Billed Charges])-275000 )*.195)+DR.[DRG Rate] ELSE 'NO' END AS StopLoss,
CASE WHEN SUM([Billed Charges]) >275000 THEN ((SUM([Billed Charges])-275000 )*.195)+DR.[DRG Rate] ELSE DR.[DRG Rate] END AS ClaimTotal
FROM raw_data AS RD
INNER JOIN DRG_Lookup_Table AS DR ON RD.DRG=DR.[DRG Code]

GROUP BY PATNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't recreate the tables I have not been able to check the code. Please try and let me know.

```
 select patno,sum(billedcharges)billedcharges,(select drg_rate 
from DRG_looking_table where drg_code=r.drg)DRG_Rate, drg, 
(case when sum(billedcharges)>275000 then (sum(billedcharges)-275000)*.195+drg_rate else 'No' end) stop_loss, 
(case when sum(billedcharges)>275000 then (sum(billedcharges)-275000)*.195+drg_rate else drg_rate end)Claim_Total
            from raw_data            GROUP BY PATNO
```

Comment: Use a proper join

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure I understand the cardinality of the records in the two tables well, but this should be fine:

```
SELECT
    t1.PATNO,
    t1.[Billed Charges] AS BilledCharges,
    t2.[DRG Rate],
    t1.DRG,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.[Billed Charges] >= 275000
        THEN (t1.[Billed Charges] - 275000)*.195 + t1.DRG
        ELSE 0
    END AS [Stop Loss],
    CASE
        WHEN t1.[Billed Charges] >= 275000
        THEN (t1.[Billed Charges] - 275000)*.195 + t1.DRG
        ELSE t2.[DRG Rate]
    END AS [Claim Total]
FROM
    (
        SELECT PATNO, DRG, SUM([Billed Charges]) AS [Billed Charges]
        FROM TABLE_1
        GROUP BY PATNO, DRG
    ) t1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.DRG = t2.[DRG Code]
```